# Unable to sync sitecore contact to CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-module

I am using Sitecore 9.0.2 and Dynamics CRM Connector 2.0.1.

While I get a contact from CRM to Sitecore using sync pipeline batch, the same gets updated in Sitecore and is synced back to CRM using the pipeline batch. This completes one cycle of update.

Now if this cointact is again updated in CRM and synced to Sitecore this works fine till here, moving on this contact gets update in Sitecore now i can see the correct details in xDB as well as indexes but these details are not getting synced to CRM this time.

Any possible reasons for such behavior ?

Thanks,
Samridhi

Comment: Can you deleting an older contact and see if it gets created with updated details ?

Comment: Where should I delete ? CRM or Sitecore ?

Comment: Select a contact in Sitecore whose details are not getting updated in CRM.Delete this contact from CRM and see if it gets recreated again with updated details in CRM

Comment: Actually the contacts from Sitecore is being synced to a temporary table in CRM as these contacts required some processing before moving to the actual contact table. thus in case the target crm table is always blank thus this test won't help use here.